# Google Maps API: Use my own coords in JavaScript API

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I am able to get my own Longitude and Latitude and save them to vars:

```
var myLat = position.coords.latitude;
var myLong = position.coords.longitude;
```

I'm just not sure how to pass them to the code that brings up the intial position of map on the screen:

```
 function initialize() {
                    var mapOptions = {
                        center: new google.maps.LatLng(-34.397, 150.644),
                        zoom: 4,
                        mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
                    };
                    var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map_canvas"),
                                                  mapOptions);
                }
```

I need to feed myLat and myLong into the line:

```
center: new google.maps.LatLng(-34.397, 150.644)
```

Im just not sure how to go about it. Can anyone point me in the right direction?

EDIT: Added full code as per request below

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=YOUR KEY HERE&sensor=true"></script>

    <script type="text/javascript">

        //MAP
        function initialize() {
            var mapOptions = {
                center: new google.maps.LatLng(-34.397, 150.644),
                zoom: 9,
                mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
            };

            map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map_canvas"),
                                  mapOptions);
        }

        //GEOLOCATION
    var onSuccess = function(position) {
        alert('Latitude: '  + position.coords.latitude   + '\n' +
              'Longitude: ' + position.coords.longitude  + '\n');

        var myLat = position.coords.latitude;
        var myLong = position.coords.longitude;

       map.setCenter(new google.maps.LatLng(myLat, myLong)) 


    };

    // onError Callback receives a PositionError object
    //
    function onError(error) {
        alert('code: '    + error.code    + '\n' +
              'message: ' + error.message + '\n');
    }

    navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(onSuccess, onError);

</script>
```

And HTML:

```
<body onload="initialize()">

 <div id="map_canvas" style="width:300px; height:400px;"></div>

</body
```

>

Comment: Why can't you just do `new google.maps.LatLng(myLat, myLng)`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The reason why this is not working is beacuse of the following function

```
var onSuccess = function(position) {

    alert('Latitude: '  + position.coords.latitude   + '\n' +
          'Longitude: ' + position.coords.longitude  + '\n');

    var myLat = position.coords.latitude;
    var myLong = position.coords.longitude;

    map.setCenter(new LatLng(myLat, myLong));
};
```

When you use

```
map.setCenter(new LatLng(myLat, myLong))
```

you have to use

```
map.setCenter(new google.maps.LatLng(myLat, myLong))
```

The LatLng object will be undefined. The Object you need to use is google.maps.LatLng.

Comment: Ah great yep that works (sort of...my app crashed but I think that'll be a different question) Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

It's just

```
var map;
function initialize() {
    //...
}

initialize();

function initiate_geolocation() {  
    navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(onSuccess);
}  

function onSuccess(position){  
    var myLat = position.coords.latitude;
    var myLong = position.coords.longitude;
    map.setCenter(new google.maps.LatLng(myLat, myLong)); // edit this line
}
initiate_geolocation();
```

It's not `map.setCenter(new LatLng(myLat, myLong));` instead it should be`map.setCenter(new google.maps.LatLng(myLat, myLong));`

[**DEMO.**](http://jsfiddle.net/heera/ty3PY/)

Comment: Thanks - I tried that and it doesnt seem to work for me. Also tried placing myLat and myLong in there too

Comment: what your myLat, myLong contains ?

Comment: full numerical latitude and longitude numbers

Answer (score 0):

You can simply pass myLat and myLong as constructor argument in              google.maps.LatLng. So your code should look like :

```
function initialize() {
var mapOptions = {
center: new google.maps.LatLng(myLat,myLong),
zoom: 4,
mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
};
var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map_canvas"),mapOptions);
}
```

Comment: Thanks, Ive tried that as well. Ive added the full code above if that makes it easier